# Printf from Linked List

Tags: c, printf, singly-linked-list

Trying to create a single linked list used to store values.
Using rank as a global placeholder, but having a problem trying to print out the value each time it increments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef struct Skill
{
    int rank;
    struct node *nextSkill;

}node;

node * addSkills(node * head);
node * createNode(node * new);

int rank = 0;

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    node * head = NULL;
    for (x = 0; x < 2; x ++)
    {
        head = addSkills(head);
        rank++;
    }
}

node * addSkills(node * head)
{
    node * newSkill = createNode(head);
    head = newSkill;
    return head;
}

node * createNode(node * new)
{
    node * newNode = calloc(1,sizeof(node));
    if(newNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation Error\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    newNode->rank = rank;
    newNode->nextSkill = new;
    return newNode;
}

void traverse(node * head)
{
    node * conductor = head;
    while(conductor != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", conductor->rank);  
        conductor = conductor->nextSkill;
    }
}
```

Not sure if my approach to creating a linked list is wrong but I can't work out why?

Comment: Please clarify what the issue is, what output you get and what output you expect, thank you

Comment: The issue is that the printf statement in the traverse function appears to skip over. I'm expecting it to print 0 then 1. I'm trying to create 2 nodes with a rank of 0 and then 1.

Comment: Hint: you can edit your question to include the additional information

Comment: You are prepending the newly created nodes instead of appending them.

Comment: Some tips: brevity is appreciated, especially on the internet, as long as it does not hinder clarity. `if(exp != 0)` is equivalent to `if(exp)`. If you shuffle the functions around, you don't need any forward-declarations. A single empty line should always be enough. (You might like to adopt a less newline-intensive style at least for posting, though that might be slightly controversial. Don't want to start a war here.)

Comment: Ok, does this cause a fault or error, such as overriding the node or just poor logic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `traverse`. Thus no output is generated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have prepends newly created nodes. That's why you get node for `1` ahead of the node for `0`. If you want append them, you can use:

```
node * addSkills(node * head)
{
   node* temp = NULL;

   if ( head == NULL )
   {
      head = createNode();
      return head;
   }

   temp = head;
   while ( temp->nextSkill != NULL )
   {
      temp = temp->nextSkill;
   }

   node * newSkill = createNode();
   temp->nextSkill = newSkill;

   return head;
}

node * createNode()
{
   node * newNode = calloc(1,sizeof(node));
   if(newNode == NULL)
   {
      printf("Memory Allocation Error\n");
      exit(2);
   }
   newNode->rank = rank;
   return newNode;
}
```

Comment: I see that the output is 0 1 0. Appending the nodes would make it read 0 1?

Comment: Made a mistake, See the same input, thanks for the help.

Comment: @choczy, BTW, I like your coding style. It has clearly defined functions that are easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let us deinfe your data structure correctly this way:

```
struct pointer
            {
            int field; 
            struct pointer *link; 
            };
typedef struct pointer cell;
```

To create your linked list, this function works fine:

```
cell *create_my_linked_list()
    {

    int n;  /* number of elements to type */
    int i;  
    int number; /*the values to input*/
    cell *ptr; /* tmp pointer */

    do
     {
     clrscr();
     cout<<"\tWhat is the length of the elements you want to create ? ";
     cin>>n;



    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
         ptr=(cell*)malloc(sizeof(cell));
         cout<<"Type a number:  ";
         scanf("%3d",&number);
         ptr->field=number;      
         ptr->link=head;         
         head=ptr;
      }
        return head;
      }
```

To display your linked list, use this simple function:

```
void display()
        {
        cell*node=head;
        if(node==NULL)
          {
          cout<<" The linked list is empty !";
          }else
              {   cout<<" VThis is your list \n";
                    while(node!=NULL)
                      {
                      printf("%3d",node->field);
                      node=node->link;
                      }
              }
          }
```

The first function above create the linked list correctly but it reverts it. It also supposes you know the length of your linked list in advance as in the case of an array. To avoid all that, use this function:

```
cell* create_a_linked_list_without_inverting_it()
    {

     cell*precedent=NULL;  

     cell*actual=NULL;     
     int datum;
     int err;

     do
      {
      cout<<" Type a number (or a letter to end) :  ";
      err=scanf("%d",&datum);
      if(err<=0) break; 
      actual=(cell*)malloc(sizeof(cell));
      actual->field=datum;
      if(precedent==NULL)
         {
         head=actual;
         }else
            {
            precedent->link=actual;
            }
      precedent=actual;
        }while(1);  
      actual->link=NULL;
      return head;
      }
```

I hope this helps.
Begueradj :)